# Puedo hacer dual-screen en linux con la gpu (integrada) y la gpu (externa)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Componentes:

- Ryzen5 2400g
- Rx580 4gb
- 8GB ddr4
  Sistema operativo: Ubuntu Mate x64

---

He habilitado el multiscreen en la bios y he probado en la opción de "Enable y Hybrid" poniendo como principal la pcie(rx580) y en ambos casos nada, no se me enciende la pantalla, he cambiado la pantalla a la salida de la grafica y funciona perfectamente pero el output de la placabase no me da señal.
Alguna solución? creo que este problema puede ayudar a mucha gente he buscado un rato por google y no encontré nada

Answer (score 0):

Prueba la solución que dan por [aquí](https://askubuntu.com/a/1305191)

1. Corre el comando `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Cambia GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT y guarda los cambios:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash amdgpu.dc=0"
   ```
3. Corre `sudo update-grub`
4. Reinicia el sistema